# Nvidia driver in Edubuntu 14.04 Lts

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04

Few days ago I've been installed the new Edubuntu 14.04 Lts distro and since than I'm trying to update the video driver becouse somtimes the monitor is blinking. It seems like the driver that is appearing to be installed " nvidia-304 " isn't the good one. I was trying to get the proper driver on Nvidia site by ''auto detect..." part,but even after I've installed the recuested Java it doesn't work.
Can anyone please help me with some info to solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this if I were you :)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-337
```